# Codeception ZF1 integration

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, codeception

I try to test my ZF project using Codeception.

First I downloaded phar file and created codeception structure (it works ok for dummy tests via `php codecept.phar run`). Then I added the following values into `tests/acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
        - ZF1
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost'
    ZF1:
        app_path: '../app'
        lib_path: '../lib'
```

and rebuild codeception (build is ok)

Then I added simple acceptance test:

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantToTest('hello action');
$I->amOnPage("/hello");
```

And now `run` command says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBootstrap() on a non-object
in phar:///var/www/myproject/tests/codecept.phar/src/Codeception
/Module/ZF1.php 
on line 119
```

Any suggestions? Why bootstrap is not initialized in codeception module?

Comment: I've got the same problem, did you already fixed it?

Comment: I noticed that the ZF1 must be in the `config:`

Answer (score 0):

The question is very old but maybe it helps someone now:

PHPBrowser module is not compatible with ZF1 module. You have to use only one of them in your suite.
So make more than one suite where you test in PHPBrowser and another suite for internal tests of your framework.

I integrated codeception(V2.3) in a big laboratory system (with zf 1.12.20) and had many errors. I wrote a complete new ZF1 module class and used their ZF1 module as template. It's not possible to give the module of codeception all configurations that you can have in a zf1 project.